# How to make Visual Studio IntelliSense (code completion) recognize Clang extension primitives

Tags: c++, intellisense, code-completion

I would like to use __fp16 (a Clang language extension) in Visual Studio, but the code is highlighted red by the Visual Studio's code completion whenever I do so. I know that my version of Clang (5_0) supports this extension, and have successfully compiled code using __fp16, but I find that IntelliSense recognizing __fp16 as an error is inconvenient and makes finding errors more difficult. Is there any way for me to configure Visual Studio's IntelliSense so that it stops marking __fp16 as an error? Thank you.

Comment: Which release of Visual Studio do you use? For Visual Studio 2017 15.7 Preview 1 ClangFormat Support is announced,, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/03/13/clangformat-support-in-visual-studio-2017-15-7-preview-1/